# Ruby - quick way to extract number from string

Tags: ruby, string, extract

As a beginner in Ruby, is there a quick to extract the first and second number from this string `5.16.0.0-15`?  In this case, I am looking `5` and `16`.  Thanks

Comment: Do you need `5` and `16` (an `Array`) or `5.16` a `Float`?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: You should write ... from the string `"5.16.0.0-15"` or ... from the string `'5.16.0.0-15'` as string objects are sequences of characters enclosed in double or single quotes. By omitting the quotes it is not clear if you mean `5` and `16` to be strings or integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the method [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-match) with the regular expression

```
rgx = /(\d+)\.(\d+)/
```

to construct a `MatchData` object. The regular expression *captures* the first two strings of digits, separated by a period. The method [MatchData#captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) is then use to extract the contents of capture groups 1 and 2 (strings) and save them to an array. Lastly, [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) is used to convert the strings in the array to integers:

```
"5.16.0.0-15".match(rgx).captures.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [5, 16]
```

We see that

```
m = "5.16.0.0-15".match(rgx)
  #=> #<MatchData "5.16" 1:"5" 2:"16">
a = m.captures
  #=> ["5", "16"]
a.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [5, 16]
```

`a.map(&:to_i)` can be thought of as shorthand for `a.map { |s| s.to_i }`.

We can express the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
/
(      # begin capture group 1
  \d+  # match one or more digits
)      # end capture group 1
\.     # match a period
(      # begin capture group 2
  \d+  # match one or more digits
)      # end capture group 2
/x     # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

---

One reason for using a regular expression here is to confirm the structure of the string, should that be desired. That could be done by using the following regex:

```
rgx1 =
/
\A       # match the beginning of the string
(        # begin capture group 1
  \d+    # match one or more digits
)        # end capture group 1
\.       # match a period
(        # begin capture group 2
  \d+    # match one or more digits
)        # end capture group 2
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  \.     # match a period
  \d+    # match one or more digits
  (?:    # begin a non-capture group
    \-   # match a hyphen
    \d+  # match one or more digits
  )?     # end non-capture group and make it optional
)*       # end non-capture group and execute it zero or more times   
\z       # match the end of the string
/x       # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
"5.16.0.0-15".match(rgx1).captures.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [5, 16]
"5.16.0.A".match(rgx1)
  #=> nil
"5.16.0.0-1-5".match(rgx1)
  #=> nil
```

The last two examples would generate exceptions because `nil` has no method `captures`. One could of course handle those exceptions.

`rgx1` is conventionally written `/\A(\d+)\.(\d+)(x?:\.\d+(?:\-\d+)?)*\z/`.

Comment: You could use a block with `match` instead e.g. `match {|m| m.captures.map(&:to_i)}` same allocations but potentially more ephemeral from a `GC` perspective since they immediately lose scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#split`, telling it to split on `"."` and only split into three parts, then access the first two.

```
irb(main):003:0> s = "5.16.0.0-15"
=> "5.16.0.0-15"
irb(main):004:0> s.split(".", 3)[0..1]
=> ["5", "16"]
```

Optionally map to integers.

```
irb(main):005:0> s.split(".", 3)[0..1].map(&:to_i)
=> [5, 16]
```

Comment: Chris could have written `s.split(".")[0..1].map(&:to_i)`. It's just a little less efficient than using [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split)'s optional second argument, which he has set to `3`. Chris, I don't think I'd recommend it, but you could write `str.split('.', 2).map(&:to_i) #=> [5, 16]`.

Comment: Not sure why you went with 3 when 2 is exactly what is needed as pointed out by @CarySwoveland.

Comment: I used `3` rather than `2` because the latter didn't isolate 16 from the remainder of the string. When using `#to_i` in this case it doesn't really matter, but it might make a difference if converting to say a float. E.g: `"5.16.7".split(".", 2).map(&:to_f)` vs. `"5.16.7".split(".", 3)[0..1].map(&:to_f)`

Comment: @Chris make sense now. Agreed not need in this case but technically `"5.16.7".to_f.to_s.split('.').map(&:to_i)` or any weird amalgamation thereof works too based on the post. Too many intermediates for my liking but functional nonetheless.

Comment: To be honest, I like the regex solution better anyway.